# Extracting bootstrapped emmeans, CI’s, and the corresponding replicates from a lme4::lmer() model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans

I am primarily looking for a sanity check here in the approach I’ve used to generate bootstrapped estimated marginal means and confidence intervals (while being able to access the replicates to plot their distribution) from a linear mixed effect model created with the lme4::lmer() package. Below is the code I’ve used. I've reviewed the relevant posts/comments here and CV, but still a bit confused.

Ultimately, the step I’m the least confident in is obtaining the actual bootstrapped estimates. What I’ve done here is simply take the mean of the replications, as I couldn’t figure out a way to access the updated estimates from the lme4::bootMer() object directly().

Thank for you any comments / critiques

```
#load packages
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(tidyverse)
library(faux)

#simulate data
set.seed(123)
data=rnorm_multi(n=20,
               varnames = c("response_t0","response_t1"),
               mu=c(100,110),
               sd=c(30,35),
               r=0.5)%>%
  mutate(id=1:20,
         condition=rep(c("A","B"),10))%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("response_t0","response_t1"),
               names_to = "time",
               names_prefix = "response_",
               values_to = "response")

#fit model
model=lmer(data = data,
           response ~ condition * time + (1 | id), REML = TRUE)

#extract emm's
emms=emmeans(model,revpairwise~time|condition)
emms.df=as.data.frame(emms$emmeans)

cont=emms$contrasts
cont.df=as.data.frame(cont)

#create function for bootstrap of contrasts
cont.boot=function(model){
  emms=emmeans(model,revpairwise~time|condition)
  cont=emms$contrasts
  cont.df=as.data.frame(cont)
  cont.df$estimate
}

#bootstrap lmm
boots=bootMer(model,cont.boot,nsim = 100)

#access replicates
boots.replicates=boots$t%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  rename(response_A=V1,
         response_B=V2)%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("response_A","response_B"),
               names_to = "condition",
               names_prefix = "response_",
               values_to = "response")
  
#access estimates from bootstrap
boots.estimates=boots.replicates%>%
  group_by(condition)%>%
  summarise(mean=mean(response))%>%
as.data.frame()

#access confidence intervals from bootstrap
boots.intervals=as.data.frame(confint(boots))%>%
  rename(lower.CL=`2.5 %`,
         upper.CL=`97.5 %`)%>%
  mutate(condition=c("A","B"))
  
#combine dfs
boots.df=cbind(boots.estimates,
subset(boots.intervals,select = c(lower.CL,upper.CL)))

#plot
ggplot(data=boots.df,
       aes(x=condition,
           y=mean,
           color=condition,
           fill=condition,
           group=condition))+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lower.CL,
                     ymax=upper.CL),
                 alpha=0.5,
                 linewidth=2,
                 lineend="round")+
  stat_slab(data=boots.replicates,
            aes(x=condition,
                y=response),
            alpha=0.33,
            width=0.5,
            trim = FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-25,50))
```

Everything here runs and ends up giving me a result, I'm just unsure if it's the best way to access the desired information.